# Do users with higher reputation have their questions start off with more votes?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question, instantly refreshed, and it seemed like I had one vote before anyone would have had time to see it.

Was this coincidence or do users with a higher reputation start their questions with > 0 votes?

Comment: Obviously the downvote is an attempt at some sort of counter proof.

Comment: That is not a *counter* proof. You only have 126 reps here. That is *very* little. So your questions automatically get two downvotes right from the get-go.

Comment: I was only asking about high reputation users - penalizing low reputation would be ridiculous (since it affects me).

Comment: 1. Giving a bonus to high rep users *is* penalizing low reputation. 2. What do you mean, downvotes affect you but upvotes do not? 3. My original statement was quite obviously a joke. So that's like a triple whoosh or something.

Comment: As was mine but maybe text isn't the best medium. And I meant that the a rule for low reputation would affect me.

Comment: *"Why do rich people have all the money?"*. Could it be that people who get lots of upvotes somehow end up with a high reputation?

Comment: It wasn't that - it was the speed at which I noticed it. I thought, maybe, it might be some side effect to having a high reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any stats that prove this (and I still don't understand the Stack Exchange Data explorer enough to compose a query) either way; but it seems reasonable that questions from users with 'high rep' might attract more interest, simply because those users are expected to know a great deal more than others without that level of reputation.

Also, it's entirely possible, that people are more forgiving of stylistic/grammatical errors in high-rep users' questions, since they've already 'proven' themselves and their understanding of, and commitment to the site; and any misunderstandings made might be ascribed to their superior knowledge (if John Skeet posts a question with a misunderstanding I'm unlikely to know better, after all).

Therefore the questions may be opened with a presumption of an interesting question, though I, personally, take the time to read a question before voting (either up or down).

Comment: Another item to consider adding to your list: It's also possible that people with higher reputation are better at forming good questions due to their significant experience at it here.